# How do I pass an array of arrays to graphql?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, graphql

So I have this array this I'm trying to send to graphql in react...

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 1, customers_top_competitors: 'asdfasd', top_competitors_url: 'https://www.asdfasd.com/', __typename: 'TopCompetitors'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Here's my query...

```
export const UPDATE_CUSTOMER_COMPETITORS = gql`
  mutation($customer_id: Int, $data: [TopCompetitorsInput]) {
    updateTopCompetitors(customer_id: $customer_id, data: $data)
  }
`;
```

and my models...

```
input TopCompetitorsInput {
  TopCompetitorsInputArray: [TopCompetitorsInputElement]
}

input TopCompetitorsInputElement {
  id: Int
  customers_top_competitors: String
  top_competitors_url: String
}
```

No matter what I try graphql doesn't like the array's index.  Comes back with this error...

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$data" got invalid value 
{ 0: { id: 1, customers_top_competitors: "asdfasd", top_competitors_url: "https://www.asdfasd.com/", 
__typename: "TopCompetitors" } }; Field "0" is not defined by type TopCompetitorsInput., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
```

Appreciate any guidance!

EDIT:

Per @Disco's request here's how I'm getting the array from the database

```
  let { data: all_data } = useQuery(GET_TOP_COMPETITORS, {
    skip: !state.customers?.selected?.id,
    variables: { customer_id: state.customers?.selected?.id },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setcompetitorData(all_data?.getTopCompetitors);
  }, [all_data]);
```

and a user can add elements to the array...

```
  const AddCompetitor = () =>
  {
    if(highestCompetitorID){
      //competitorData.push({id: highestCompetitorID, customers_top_competitors: '', top_competitors_url: ''}); 
      setcompetitorData((competitorData) => [...competitorData, {id: highestCompetitorID, customers_top_competitors: '', top_competitors_url: ''}])
      sethighestCompetitorID(competitorData[competitorData.length - 1].id + 1)
    }else {
      //competitorData.push({id: 1, customers_top_competitors: '', top_competitors_url: ''}); 
      setcompetitorData((competitorData) => [...competitorData, {id: 1, customers_top_competitors: '', top_competitors_url: ''}]); 
      sethighestCompetitorID(competitorData[competitorData.length - 1].id + 1)
    }
  }
```

EDIT 2:  here is the result of console.log(JSON.stringify(competitorData));...

[{"id":1,"customers_top_competitors":"sdfasfdfasdfsd","top_competitors_url":"https://www.asdfdfasd.com/","__typename":"TopCompetitors"}]

EDIT 3: Played around with the graphql interface and tried the data like my react is sending.  Plus have one that was successful.

[image]

[image]

Final Edit:

So I found a way to make my code work by passing the array elements 1 by 1.  This can't be the best way.  But maybe this will help someone else.  Here's what worked...

```
<Button
  color="orange"
  type="submit"
  onClick={() => {
    for(let x = 0; x < competitorData?.length; x++)
    {
      updateCustomerCompetitors({
        variables: {
          customer_id: state.customers?.selected?.id,
          data: omit(competitorData[x], ["__typename"])
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: If `competitorData ` then you should not push to it directly. 
setcompetitorData((oldState) => [...oldState, {id: highestCompetitorID, customers_top_competitors: '', top_competitors_url: ''}])

Could just try to print the array before you pass it as data? 
Printing it as console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) might help in this case.

Comment: @Disco Updated the question with the output of console.log

Comment: I have had a problem before when I pass `__typename`, try to  omit that from the object. 
And as I mentioned below when the data is `[{"id":1,"customers_top_competitors":"sdfasfdfasdfsd","top_competitors_url":"https://www.asdfdfasd.com/","__typename":"TopCompetitors"}]`
Should be of type `$data: [TopCompetitorsInputElement]` if you do not do anymore with the data

Comment: @Disco What's weird is if I just send the first element of the array data: omit(competitorData?.[0], ["__typename"]) it passes correctly to graphql.  I'm stumped.

Comment: If you are using Apollo you could use apollo playground to get a overview of your mutations and queries and test them manually. Would probably help you in this case. I dont know if I can add anymore to this issue. Hope that you can solve it

Answer (score 2):

In your code you say that the $data is of the type Array of `TopCompetitorsInput`  which is a object with a field `TopCompetitorsInputArray`  that have a array of `TopCompetitorsInputElement`  as value.

Either change:
If you just want to pass on the Array that you have:

```
export const UPDATE_CUSTOMER_COMPETITORS = gql`
  mutation($customer_id: Int, $data: [TopCompetitorsInputElement]) {
    updateTopCompetitors(customer_id: $customer_id, data: $data)
  }
`;
```

Or change it to just the input and pass the data as a object

```
export const UPDATE_CUSTOMER_COMPETITORS = gql`
  mutation($customer_id: Int, $data: TopCompetitorsInput) {
    updateTopCompetitors(customer_id: $customer_id, data: $data)
  }
`;
```

Per your typings the data input should look like this

```
{
  TopCompetitorsInputArray: <Your array here>
}
```

Comment: So I tried your idea of referencing the TopCompetitorInput object.  mutation($customer_id: Int, $data: TopCompetitorsInput)  but it's still coming back with this error...  [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$data" got invalid value { 0: { id: 1, customers_top_competitors: "asdfasdf", top_competitors_url: "https://www.asdfasd.com/", __typename: "TopCompetitors" } } at "data.TopCompetitorsInputArray"; Field "0" is not defined by type TopCompetitorsInputElement., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

Comment: I would then look at you actual data, looks like something is wrong there. Looks like your index of the array becomes the key of a field. 
Could you post how you create the data array in this case?

Comment: thanks for your advice.  I've updated my question with how i'm getting the array.